# Why do I get "Access denied for user 'root'@'myhostname" when connecting to my database in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1045

I have set up an Apache server on mandriva linux 2010.1. But the problem is whenever I'm trying to connect with the database, it's giving me the following error:

> Error:Database error: SQLSTATE[28000]
>   [1045] Access denied for user
>   'root'@'myhostname' (using password:
>   YES)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally for a web application, you shouldn't connect to the database as `root`. However you tagged your post as `[phpmyadmin]` so I assume your issue is with, well, phpMyAdmin, in which case you might be connecting as root.

If this is the case, I see that you mentioned `myhostname` in your error message. Have you tried connecting to `localhost` instead? Sometimes the MySQL `root` user cannot connect from remote hosts.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set some configuration variables for phpmyadmin to work:
http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/Documentation.html#config

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO monty@localhost
       IDENTIFIED BY 'indian' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Replace your username and password and execute it in your phpmyadmin by selecting your database.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ["5.4.7. Causes of Access-Denied Errors"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html) in the MySQL online documentation and [Using authentication modes"](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/Documentation.html#authentication_modes) in the PHPMyAdmin documentation.